# How to implement Configuration Service 5.0 of the StockTrader 5.0 sample application?

Tags: wcf, configuration

We have a collection of WCF Rest WebServices. Those WebServices are having configuration strings that are now hard coded as constants. We want to be able to change those configuration strings at runtime. A colleague of mine pointed me at the Configuration Service of the [StockTrader sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684).

I installed the sample application and looked at working of the application. The Configuration Service is just a little part of the sample application. The documentation of the sample application contains a tutorial for the '[Visual Studio Configuration Service template](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/C/9/7C9F7B89-8AF0-4433-AB3A-B615C8EF9484/ConfigServiceVSTemplate.pdf)', wich I followed. After that I found the 'Config Service Technical Guide' in the documentation folder of the sample application, wich contains a sort of action plan on page 12. The actionplan is just a summary what has to be implemented to use Configuration Service, not how it has to be implemented. Above the action plan the reader is referred to the *'Guide to Implementing the Configuration Service 5.0 for .NET Applications and Services'*. Only thing after googling: The guide is nowhere to be found..

With the combination of the little actionplan in the technical guide, the comments in the code of the VS Template and the technical guide, I made a start to extract the Configuration Service and try to implement it in a new solution to test it. Now I am stuck with the implementation of the ConfigurationActionsBase. The implementation of the ConfigurationActionsBase persists the changes of the configuration to the database.

- Does anyone know where the missing guide is(mentioned in the story
  above)?
- Does anyone know how to extract the configuration of magic
  strings out of the StockTrader sample application?
- Does anyone know an alternative solution for our scenario?

With Kind Regards,